# jQuery delay and keyup

Tags: jquery, delay, onkeyup

HI guys,

What I'm trying to do is to display the animated gif while someone is typing text into the text field with keyup and once they've finished typing, the gif to disappear and display message 'Saved' for a few seconds, which would then disappear.

What I've done so far is:

```
if ($('.gallery_items li input').length > 0) {
    $('.gallery_items li input').keyup(function() {         
        var li = $(this).parent();
        li.children('.gallery_saving').removeClass('dn');
        var identity = li.attr('id').split('_');
        var v = $(this).val();
        var url = '/caption/id/' + identity[1];
        $.post(url, { caption : v });   
        $.delay(500).li.children('.gallery_saving').delay(500).html('Saved...').delay(500).addClass('dn');          
        return false;
    });
}
```

Where class 'gallery_saving' has animated gif assigned as background image and class 'dn' has simply css 'display:none'.
Initially 'gallery_saving' has class 'dn' as well - so that it isn't visible, when someone starts typing the class 'dn' is removed - showing the loader.

You obviously see the problem already with:

```
$.delay(500).li.children('.gallery_saving').delay(500).html('Saved...').delay(500).addClass('dn');
```

and I know it's wrong, but can't figure out how to do it - can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide HTML to work with?

Comment: Be careful with your understanding of [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), it does state: _"Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue"_ - but it is for the effects queue, not everything. Take a look at [this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xG8Hf/3/), you will see [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) without any arguments isn't an effect so isn't delayed, neither is [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) an effect so again isn't delayed, but [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) is an effect, so it does get delayed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the loader not on delay time, but on succesful safe of the entered data..

Something like

```
url = "/echo/html";
v = "test";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: ({ caption: v}),
  success: function(){
    $('.gallery_saving').html('Saved...').delay(1000).fadeToggle("slow");
  },
  error:  function() {
    $('.gallery_saving').html('Error...').delay(1000).fadeToggle("slow");
  }
});
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gabel/udvbx/

Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for Details...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particularly good idea to try and do this, because you'll end up making a lot of ajax calls if the user hasn't actually finished typing. If the user is a slow at typing, you will be saving the data a lot of times for no reason.

You could also use `show()` and `hide()` instead of the `dn` class. Or use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: that's true - you shouldn't dos your own server with post request by just typing.. blur or timeout should be used to prevent that behavior.

Comment: I think you're right guys - blur might be a bit tricky as someone might leave the cursor in the text field and click the link to go to another page and I believe the same applies to timeout - so presumably the best option would be to have the Save button somewhere - not as sophisticated, but will do the job I guess.